# Как правильно реализовать удаление устаревших записей в БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Суть задачи такова: в базе хранятся токены срок годности которых 24 часа. Если пользователь обращается к токену спустя 24 часа, то ничего не происходит. Устаревшие токены нужно удалять.

Мои варианты решения таковы:

1. Делать запрос в БД на удаление устаревших токенов каждый раз при обращении к главной странице сайта. Даже при минимальной посещаемости - токены будут удалятся, но мы получаем большое количество лишних запросов. Вариант кажется избыточным.
2. Удалять токены только в тот момент когда пользователь к ним обращается. То есть при запросе токена, проверяем вместе с его сроком годности срок годности всех остальных. Тут уже не будет гораздо меньше запросов, но есть вероятность что к токенам вообще не обратятся, и тогда база будет накапливать в себе кучу неактуальной информации.

*Вопрос*: как правильно реализовать корректное удаление токенов спустя ровно 24 часа?

Comment: не то и другое не подходит?

Comment: @RomanC , у меня нету опыта, поэтому я решил посоветоваться тут с более грамотными и опытными людьми , какой вариант лучше, или может быть есть что то гораздо проще, а я изобретаю велосипед

Comment: Пишете запрос, удаляющий старые токены (DELETE FROM). Создаёте задание (CREATE EVENT), выполняющее этот запрос, скажем, ежеминутно. Запускаете Event Sheduler. Всё.

Comment: Ну устаревшими считаются те, которые вы укажете в условии запроса, вы можете запускать `INTERVAL` на определенный период, для сбора устаревшей в вашем представлении информации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете скрипт, который выгребает с базы все токены у которых истек срок годности и удаляете их. И запускаете этот скрипт скажем раз в час при помощи [Cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Или раз в сутки

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт который запускается с помощью cron, как уже сказали.

Я посоветую ещё обратить внимание на memcached.
Для такой задачи может подойти хранение в memcached, там с помощью php интерфейса можно задавать время жизни записи.

```
public bool Memcached::add ( string $key , mixed $value [, int$expiration ] )
```

Кажется для вашей задачи самое то.